# How to generate random passwords for PDF files using a batch program

Tags: batch-file, passwords, pdf-generation

I need some help. I am currently doing a batch program that does the following:

In the \Reports\ folder several text files are stored. For example,

A_000100.txt, A_000200.txt, B_000100.txt, B_000200.txt, C_000100.txt, C_000200.txt, D_000100.txt, D_000200.txt, E_000100.txt, E_000200.txt, F_000100.txt, F_000200.txt

1. All the text files must be individually converted into PDF using Command Line. To address this, I installed the program "AdultPDF Txt to PDF converter". It has Command Line functions that converts text files into PDF with different parameters. Below is a line that shows how a text file is converted into PDF. In the sample code below, the output PDF file's paper is set to letter size (-pps4) and the font size is 10.9 (-pfs10.9).

`TXTtoPDF A_000100.txt A_000100.pdf -pps4 -pfs10.9`

1. After each text files are individually converted into PDF, the PDF files which have the same last 6 characters on their filenames (example, A_000100.pdf, B_000100.pdf, C_000100.pdf, etc.) should be combined into a single PDF and the output filename will be R_000100.pdf. The output PDF file will be stored in the same folder.
2. The combined PDF file (example, R_000100.pdf) must be encrypted with a password, but it should be randomly generated. But the passwords of each combined PDF file should be different from one another.

   - To address items number 2 & 3, I installed the program PDFTK (or PDF ToolKit). It has Command Line functions that combines PDF files with different parameters, including adding password into a PDF file. Below is a line that shows how to combine multiple PDF files into one, and adding a random password into the PDF file.

`pdftk *%%i.pdf cat output R_%%i.pdf owner_pw %random%`

1. And lastly, a log file (.CSV) should be created that will list the filenames of the combined PDF files together with the randomly generated passwords for each PDF file. Below is the code I used to do this:

`echo %%i R_%%i.pdf %random% >> passwords.csv`

Actually, the generation of the random password and storing them into a CSV file is where I'm having a problem. It doesn't seem to work. I can't figure out how to do it correctly. Can anyone who is proficient in batch programming please help me? Below is the complete batch program I have accomplished so far. If there are some corrections that need to be done to my program to make it simpler, don't hesitate to correct it. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=ABCDEF_." %%i in ('dir *.txt *.pdf /b') do (

TXTtoPDF A_%%i.txt A_%%i.pdf -pps4 -pfs10.9
TXTtoPDF B_%%i.txt B_%%i.pdf -pps4 -pfs8.9
TXTtoPDF C_%%i.txt C_%%i.pdf -pps4 -plm50 -prm50 -pfs7.9
TXTtoPDF D_%%i.txt D_%%i.pdf -pps4 -plm60 -prm60 -pfs8.9
TXTtoPDF E_%%i.txt E_%%i.pdf -pps5 -pot -pfs10
TXTtoPDF F_%%i.txt F_%%i.pdf -pps5 -pot -pfs12
pdftk *%%i.pdf cat output PDF\R_%%i.pdf owner_pw %random%
echo %%i R_%%i.pdf %random% >> passwords.csv

)

echo                ***************************************************
echo                *                                                 *
echo                *       PDF REPORTS SUCCESSFULLY GENERATED.       *
echo                *       PLEASE TYPE EXIT AT COMMAND PROMPT.       *
echo                *                                                 *
echo                ***************************************************
pause
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delayed expansion - within a block, any %var% including %random% is replaced by its value at the time the block (parenthesised statement-sequence) is PARSED.

Solution is to invoke `DELAYED EXPANSION` using a statement

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

after the `@echo off`

**THEN** you need to access the changing value of `random` by accessing `!random!` rather than `%random%`

**BUT** you need to send the same random value to the file as is used for your password and `!RANDOM!` will generate a new value each time it's accessed - SO you need to put the varying random value into a variable and use the varying value stored in your variable as both password and data in your CSV

```
set pass=!random!
pdftk *%%i.pdf cat output PDF\R_%%i.pdf owner_pw !pass!
echo %%i R_%%i.pdf !pass! >> passwords.csv
```

naturally, you need `!pass!` not `%pass%` to access the new value of `pass` as it varies within the loop.

Now - the random number may be 1-5 digits in length. You may wish to have a longer or constant-length password

```
set pass=!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!
```

would set `pass` to a 6 to 30-digit string.

```
set pass=!pass:~0,8!
```

would select the first 8 of these characters. (the probability of fewer than 8 characters is very low)

---

edit 20130718T1446Z

Hmm. Interesting little adventure. I just solved the password issue, no doubt misled by the statement `"Actually, the generation of the random password and storing them into a CSV file is where I'm having a problem"`

OK - first, there's no point in listing both *.txt AND *.pdf. Only the *.txt will be processed by the TXTtoPDF executable. Then the DELIMS... yes - putting the alphas in there neatly got rid of the leading alpha and underscore, leaving just the numeric portion.

So... why the repeats? First the `dir` would examine the current directory and build a list of matching files, (I'll truncate)  A_001, A_002, A_003...B_001, B_002...F_001, F_002, F_003 and then the FOR would pick out the 001,002,003...001,002,003...001,002,003 and process them. Consequently, the 001, 002, 003 each get processed 6 times. The final processing of any particular number would cause the A_,B_,...F_ to be executed, overwriting previous x_999.PDF so the LAST password applied inthe case of any particular number would be the final version.

Revised code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET prevsuff=::

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_." %%i in ('dir ?_*.txt /b ^|sort /+2') do IF NOT !prevsuff!==%%j (
 SET prevsuff=%%j
 IF EXIST A_%%j.txt TXTtoPDF A_%%j.txt A_%%j.pdf -pps4 -pfs10.9
 IF EXIST B_%%j.txt TXTtoPDF B_%%j.txt B_%%j.pdf -pps4 -pfs8.9
 IF EXIST C_%%j.txt TXTtoPDF C_%%j.txt C_%%j.pdf -pps4 -plm50 -prm50 -pfs7.9
 IF EXIST D_%%j.txt TXTtoPDF D_%%j.txt D_%%j.pdf -pps4 -plm60 -prm60 -pfs8.9
 IF EXIST E_%%j.txt TXTtoPDF E_%%j.txt E_%%j.pdf -pps5 -pot -pfs10
 IF EXIST F_%%j.txt TXTtoPDF F_%%j.txt F_%%j.pdf -pps5 -pot -pfs12
 set pass=!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!
 set pass=!pass:~-8!
 pdftk *%%j.pdf cat output PDF\R_%%j.pdf owner_pw !pass!
 echo %%j R_%%j.pdf !pass! >> passwords.csv

)

GOTO :EOF
```

(OK- I've left off the message-block frippery...)

Initially, `prevsuff` is st to `::` - a non-empty string that cannot possibly be a filename. Then the `DIR` is executed, finding all files that match `?_*.txt` and that list is sorted in alphabetical order on the second column - the `_`. Consequently, when `FOR` processes the data, the lines are presented with all of the NUMBER part grouped. It applies the prefix letter to `%%i` and the numeric part to `%%j` because of the `_` in the `delims`. the `.` in the delims drops the `.txt` suffix from `%%j`

(well, Ok - this could have been written `tokens=2delims=_.` which would apply the numeric part to `%%i` - exercise for those interested...)

Now if the numeric part (`%%j`) does not match the `previous suffix` in `prevsuff` then we process this one. First we adjust `prevsuff` to the one we're about to process, then process it. Then when we get the next number from the list, it'll match so we skip until we have the next change...

The `IF EXIST`s are to suppress ugly messages if there's a file missing (A_001 exists, but D_001 doesn't...); 8 randoms are cascaded into `pass` so there will be 8..40 digits assigned, and the LAST 8 are chosen by the `!pass:~-8!`

From there, it should be plain sailing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! It really worked. Also thanks for providing the code on how to extend the password length and to select the first 8 characters from the password. That's the exact length that I need for the password.

Comment: I'm still having an issue with regards to the program I posted above. I think there is a problem in my for loop statement because after I opened the file "passwords.csv", I noticed that the loop repeated 5 times. For example, R_000100.pdf was in rows 1, 3, 5, 7, and 9 with different passwords. But the last password is the right one. What should I correct so that after the all the PDF files have been combined and assigned with passwords, the program will already stop the loop and exit? Thus having only one entry in the output file "passwords.csv" and won't repeat 5 times. Thank you so much!